# run 2 similar javascripts on the same page

Tags: javascript, methods, sharepoint-2013

I have 2 js files in the site asset directory on SPS2013. The code in each is similar.I need to use each script on the same SharePoint page in 2 content editor web parts (CEWP). I read on this thread "run 2 identical javascripts on the same page" that changing the method names resolves this kind of issue however, I have not managed to accomplish this. Each script runs as expected when there is only one CEWP on the page, when I add the other, the results from both end up in the same CEWP.

I have renamed all the methods and the ID of the DIV that I am outputting to. I don't get any errors in the console. I would have thought that each script running inside a  tag would help but no luck. I'm not sure if this a SharePoint ism or a JS ism. Very new to JS so please keep it simple.

I added both scripts below:

Script 1

```
<html>
<style type='text/css'> .tablewrapperEU { position: relative;  box-sizing: border-box; height:72px} .tableEU {display: table; } .rowEU { display: table-row; padding: 1px; } .cellEU { display: table-cell; border: none solid red; padding: 3px;} .cell.empty { border: none; width: 75px; } .cell.rowspanned {  position: absolute; top: 0;  bottom: 0; width: 75px; display: block; margin: 1px;} .contacts{ width: 72px; height: 72px;} .flag { width: 30px; height: 20px; }</style>
<div class="myEUClass" id="divListItemsEU"></div></html>



<script type="text/javascript">


var $eu = jQuery.noConflict(true);


$eu(function () {



    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveEUListItems, "sp.js");




});



function retrieveEUListItems() {

    //get the cuurent location context of the page we are on

    var clientContextEU = new SP.ClientContext();

    // get the list/table from the web site where the page is located

    var oList = clientContextEU.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('WhosWho');

    //

    //create a query to get all list items int he defult view

    var camlQueryEU = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQueryEU.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" +
            "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ElementContactRegion\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">EU</Value></Eq></Where>" +
        "</Query>"+
        "</View>");
    //create an array of list items

    this.collListItemEU = oList.getItems(camlQueryEU);

    //load the list items into context 

    clientContextEU.load(collListItemEU);

    //execute the query 

    clientContextEU.executeQueryAsync(



    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),



    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)



    );
clientContextEU.dispose();


}



function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    // Might be worth starting with this here just to ensure the div is always clear before we start.

    $eu("#divListItemsEU").html('');


    var listEUItemInfoEU = '';


    var listItemEnumeratorEU = collListItemEU.getEnumerator();

    //Iterate results


    while (listItemEnumeratorEU.moveNext()) {

        // get the current looped item

        var oListItemEU = listItemEnumeratorEU.get_current();


        // get the userID from the lookup field

        var w = oListItemEU.get_item('ContactFullName').get_lookupId();
        var x = oListItemEU.get_item('ContactJobTitleFT');
        var y = oListItemEU.get_item('ContactRegion');

        // pass it into the get email method 

        getEUEmail(w,x, y, function(returnedValueEU) {

            //console.log(returnedValue[0])

            $eu("#divListItemsEU").append(



                    returnedValueEU[0]  + 

                    //oListItem.get_item('ElementContactFullName').get_lookupValue() +

                   // ' <strong>JobTitle:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('ElementContactJobTitle').get_lookupValue() +


                    '<br />');
});

    }



    // display data

    $eu("#divListItemsEU").html(listEUItemInfoEU);

}



function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {



    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +



    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());


}



 function getEUEmail(userId, JT,  flag, callback) {



    var xEU = [];

    var contextEU = new SP.ClientContext();

    var webEU = contextEU.get_web();

    var user = webEU.get_siteUsers().getById(userId);

    contextEU.load(user);



    contextEU.executeQueryAsync(function() {

        //console.log(user.get_email());

        var yEU =   "<div class='tablewrapperEU'>" +
      "<div class='tableEU'>" +
        "<div class='rowEU'>" +
          "<div class='rowspanned cell'>" +
             ' <img class="contacts" src="' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname='+ user.get_email()  +'"/>' +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='cellEU'>" +
           user.get_title() +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='rowEU'>" +
          "<div class='empty cell'></div>" +
          "<div class='cellEU'>" +
            JT +  
          "<div class='cellEU'>" +
         ' <img class="flag" src="' + window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host   + '/SiteAssets/Images/'+ flag  +'.png"/>' +
         //http://staging.intranet.ent.sys.element.com/SiteAssets/Images/EU.png
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
    "</div>"







        xEU.push(yEU);

        callback(xEU);



    }

    , function() {

        console.log("error");

    });
contextEU.dispose();
}

</script>
```

Script 2

```
<script src="/style%20library/javascript/intranet/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<style type='text/css'> .tablewrapper { position: relative;  box-sizing: border-box; height:72px} .table {display: table; } .row { display: table-row; padding: 1px; } .cell { display: table-cell; border: none solid red; padding: 3px;} .cell.empty { border: none; width: 75px; } .cell.rowspanned {  position: absolute; top: 0;  bottom: 0; width: 75px; display: block; margin: 1px;} .contacts{ width: 72px; height: 72px;} .flag { width: 30px; height: 20px; }</style>
<div class="myAllClass" id="divListItems"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var $sr = jQuery.noConflict(true);


$sr(function () {

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

});



function retrieveListItems() {

    //get the cuurent location context of the page we are on

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

    // get the list/table from the web site where the page is located

    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('WhosWho');

    //create a query to get all list items int he defult view

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ElementContactRegion\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">US</Value></Eq></Where>" +
        "</Query>"+
        "</View>");


    //create an array of list items

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    //load the list items into context 

    clientContext.load(collListItem);


    //execute the query 

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(



    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),



    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)



    );

 clientContext.dispose();

}



function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    // Might be worth starting with this here just to ensure the div is always clear before we start.

    $sr("#divListItems").html('');


    var listItemInfo = '';


    var listItemEnumerator = this.collListItem.getEnumerator();

    //Iterate results


    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        // get the current looped item

        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();


        // get the userID from the lookup field

        var t = oListItem.get_item('ContactFullName').get_lookupId();
        var u = oListItem.get_item('ContactJobTitleFT');
        var v = oListItem.get_item('ContactRegion');


        // pass it into the get email method 

        getEmail(t,u, v, function(returnedValue) {

            //console.log(returnedValue[0])

            $sr("#divListItems").append(



                    returnedValue[0]  + 

                    //oListItem.get_item('ElementContactFullName').get_lookupValue() +

                   // ' <strong>JobTitle:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('ElementContactJobTitle').get_lookupValue() +


                    '<br />');
});

    }




    // display data

    $sr("#divListItems").html(listItemInfo);


}



function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {



    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +



    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());


}



 function getEmail(userId, JT,  flag, callback) {



    var x = [];

    var context = new SP.ClientContext();

    var web = context.get_web();

    var user = web.get_siteUsers().getById(userId);

    context.load(user);



    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {

        //console.log(user.get_email());

        var y =   "<body><div class='tablewrapper'>" +
      "<div class='table'>" +
        "<div class='row'>" +
          "<div class='rowspanned cell'>" +
             ' <img class="contacts" src="' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=M&accountname='+ user.get_email()  +'"/>' +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='cell'>" +
           user.get_title() +
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row'>" +
          "<div class='empty cell'></div>" +
          "<div class='cell'>" +
            JT +  
          "<div class='cell'>" +
         '<img class="flag" src="' + window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host   + '/SiteAssets/Images/'+ flag  +'.png"/>' +
         //http://staging.intranet.ent.sys.element.com/SiteAssets/Images/EU.png
          "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
    "</div>"


        x.push(y);

        callback(x);



    }

    , function() {

        console.log("error");

    });
context.dispose();
}

</script>
```

To reiterate, why wont these run together in seperate CEWPs on a SharePoint page?

Comment: I have also tried changing $ to jQuery, setting a variable to jQuery.noConfict(true) but it still gets mangled by SharePoint.

Comment: I do not have idea on sharepoint. But I suggest you to have only one simple method/function in both js to try and then find out why it is not working. The big file with so many lines of code may make it too much complicated to identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you said you changed all ids of the divs, but did you change the code also to match the changed ids? Probably thats the issue.. the code is second file is referring to ids of html divs used in first one.

Comment: Yes I did change the ID of main DIV declared at the top of the page. and also changed the ````$("#divListItemsEU").html(''); to reflect the DIV ID

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the onQuerySucceeded/fail functions in one of the scripts. To be fair I did try this a few day beforehand but I obviously didn't change everywhere in the script.

Example:

```
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryEUSucceeded),



    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryEUFailed)



    );
clientContextEU.dispose();


}



function onQueryEUSucceeded(sender, args) {
```